# Publicar una entrada en blogger usando la Api y php

Tags: php, api, blogger

Intento enviar un `Post` a `Blogger` usando la `Api v3` de `Blogger` Y `Php` . El código funciona bien pero tengo unas dudas de como actualizar el **token**  sin dar nuevamente permisos pensé que con esta parte:

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

No necesitaba actualizarlo.

Otra duda es por que no puedo enviar una imagen usando esta manera :

```
$post->setimages(array("url"=>"https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/casa-dos-pisos_1308-16176.jpg"));
```

No aparece la imagen publicada .
Segun este enlace [Posts: insert](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert) esa es la manera o eso entiendo .

Les dejo el código completo para que puedan entender y ayudarme .

```
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    $scriptUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('B'); //name of the application
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri); //redirects to same url
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
    $client->setAccessType('offline'); // default: offline
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Blogger::BLOGGER);
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true); // incremental auth
    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
    $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it in session
//authenticate using the parameter $_GET['code'] you got from google server
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

//get the access token
$tokens = $client->getAccessToken();
file_put_contents(__DIR__."/Data/token.json", $tokens); 
}

    $service = new Google_Service_Blogger($client);
    $blog = $service->blogs->getByUrl('http://Miblog.mx/');
    //this is part for sending post into blogger, which is getting
    //error
    $post = new Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
    $post->setTitle('poner imagen 3');
    $post->setImages(array("url"=>"https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/casa-dos-pisos_1308-16176.jpg"));
    $post->setLabels(array('Label1', 'Label2'));
    $post->setContent("plantilla.html");
    $service->posts->insert('203422', $post);
```

Esta parte tampoco funciona como yo espero.

```
$post->setContent("plantilla.html");
```

No publica el **html** de `"plantilla.html"` y no se por que o como se logra 
y e buscado en Internet y no hay mucha información en español

Comment: Tienes una errata. Es [`setImages()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Blogger/Post.php#L109) (con la 'I' mayúscula) y no `setimages()` (con `i` minúscula). La parte final de este código no debería funcionar porque se genera un error que finaliza la ejecución del script antes de insertar el `$post`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia verifique esa parte pero tampoco manda la imagen

Comment: ¿Podrías actualizar la pregunta con el código actualizado con el cambio de ese método? ¿Esta parte es inventada? `$blog = $service->blogs->getByUrl('http://whatsapp.mx/');` lo digo porque no usas `$blog` ni creo que te devuelva ningún resultado (whatsapp no forma parte de blogger). Además, ¿tu aplicación `B` tiene acceso al blog? ¿Te agrega entradas aunque sea sin imágenes (imagino que el `blogId` es `203422`)?

Comment: Esas partes no son reales estan para un caso de ejemplo

Comment: Aunque no tengo experiencia, en particular, usando el API de Google para Blogger, tengo experiencia con otras APIs de Google como la de Youtube y Fotos. Por norma general los problemas que he tenido han sido o por permisos o por no entender correctamente a qué hacían referencia los parámetros. He terminado dando vueltas por el código del repositorio de Google sin resultados (he llegado hasta el código que hace efectivo el `$service->posts->insert()`), pero tendría que crear un blog de pruebas para probar las opciones y saber qué son las imágenes y las plantillas (creo que no son archivos).

Comment: Real mente el código funciona y publica la entrada sin poner la imagen como archivo adjunto lo cual se puede arreglar con un poco de css y html . si se pudiera publicar la plantilla.html y otro detalle es que no se como actualizar el token sin tener que estar dando permiso tal ves en eso si puedas darme una idea

Comment: Para no extender la conversación en comentarios, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105397/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-botxtrem-solutions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a responder cada una de las preguntas en un apartado.

### Con `setAccessType('offline')` no necesito actualizar el token

Estamos tratando con tokens OAuth, por lo que tal y como puede [leerse en la documentación](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline), el modo `offline` permite que la aplicación refresque el token sin interacción con el usuario: sin necesidad de que el usuario esté presente en un navegador o deba validar de nuevo los permisos.

Pero los tokens siempre tienen un tiempo de expiración e incluso un tiempo de renovación máximo. Con esa opción delegas el trabajo el cliente PHP, pero si se superan los plazos de renovación del token se deberá solicitar el acceso al usuario de nuevo.

Un procedimiento de refresco del token puedes verlo en cualquier ejemplo del [repositorio `php-samples`](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/php-samples). Muestro el ejemplo del [acceso al calendario](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/php-samples/blob/f77a37774957d9dd4767a065d91735258948afd3/calendar/quickstart/quickstart.php#L41):

```
/* Archivo que guardará el token para sucesivas ejecuciones */
$tokenPath = 'token.json';
if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    /* Cargamos los datos del archivo */
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    /* Lo cargamos en el cliente de Google */
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}

/* Si no había token o está expirado */
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    /* Refrescamos el token si es posible, o solicitamos uno nuevo */
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        /* Si no se pudo renovar el token solicitamos una nueva autorización al usuario */
    }
    /* Guardamos el token en el archivo */
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

### Otra duda es por que no puedo enviar una imagen usando esta manera

He probado el API de Blogger y no es posible agregar una imagen a un post, ni externo (como el que indicaste) ni previamente cargado con la herramienta de subida de imágenes (las URLs comienzan por `https://4.bp.blogspot.com/`) ni desde el álbum personal del autor del post (las URLs comienzan por `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/`).

Aunque [en la documentación](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts#images) pone:

> - `images[]` (`list`): Display image for the Post.
> - `images[].url` (`string`)

En la práctica, incluso haciendo uso de la función **Try this API**, no he sido capaz de insertar ninguna imagen como imagen para mostrar (aunque sí he podido poner una imagen para mostrar agregando una imagen dentro del contenido) y no he podido obtener ningún resultado de búsqueda con el índice `images` exceptuando en el icono del usuario autor de un post o un comentario.

Creo que este campo se usa cuando se consulta un dato de una publicación que sí que tiene imagen para mostrar, no para cambiar la imagen para mostrar a la que deseemos.

### `$post->setContent("plantilla.html")` no funciona como espero

Esta parte es la más sencilla de aclarar. El parámetro de la función es el contenido de la publicación, no un archivo que contenga el contenido de la publicación.

De modo que debes cargar el contenido del archivo haciendo uso de, por ejemplo, [`file_get_contents()`](https://php.net/es/file_get_contents):

```
$post->setContent(file_get_contents("plantilla.html"));
```

Comment: perfecto tan solo te falto explicar un poco como es el método de refrescar el token lo demás esta muy claro

Comment: Dame unos minutos, estoy haciendo pruebas porque parece que por sí solo el modo `offline` no refresca el token de acceso. Permite el refresco, pero éste no es automático.

Comment: Sin problema tomate tu tiempo

Comment: Una pregunta, durante la primera redirección (en `setRedirectUri` pones el mismo PHP), ¿tienes código que gestione esa redirección que no has publicado o no lo gestionas?. Si lo tienes, ¿podrías compartirlo? debo agregar código en él para guardar el token de refresco para su posterior uso.

Comment: Esa es una de las ideas de guardar el token en un json para usarlo mediante cron por eso me interesa si es posible actualizarlo sin tener que ser yo el que lo autorice

Comment: Ya esta actualizado con una manera simple de respaldar el token

Comment: La primera autorización siempre ha de darla el usuario. Una vez que tienes el token puedes usarlo durante más tiempo. Ahora estoy en tránsito, en cuanto llegue a un ordenador edito mi respuesta y agrego cómo guardar el token de refresco y cómo usarlo para refrescar el token de acceso.

Comment: Para darte una respuesta exacta con tu código lo estoy reproduciendo en el siguiente repositorio de github: https://github.com/ojgarciab/334603-stackoverflow-es . Tengo que dejar aparcado esto un rato porque tengo otras tareas por hacer. Cuando lo actualice te aviso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105423/discussion-between-botxtrem-solutions-and-oscargarcia).